# How do I cite two quotes from the same author in one sentence in Harvard?

Tags: citations

I'm citing different quotes/paraphrases with different pages by the same author in most of my sentences and paragraphs and need a way to properly cite them. For example:

X argues that "blah blah blah" which shows he has a Y approach, but then further argues that "blah blah blah", showing a different approach.

So far I'm going with this: X argues that "blah blah blah" (X, 1999: 31) which shows he has a Y approach, but then further argues that "blah blah blah" (X, 1999: 98), showing a different approach.

I'm using up my word count, so what would be the most efficient way of doing this using Harvard method of referencing?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: “Demonstrating Y approach” uses fewer words...

Comment: What about "X argues '...' and '...', showing both approach Y and Z are applicable (X, 1999:31, X,1999:98)"?

Comment: What about "ibid., 89"?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

**X paradoxically demonstrates both X approach ("blah blah blah") [1] and Y approach ("blah2 blah2 blah2") [2].**